What causes android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce to appear in stack traces, and how can I resolve it?
I am firebase a ARN in my Android application, and I see android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce repeatedly in the stack trace. Below is a snippet of the
main (native):tid=1 systid=11683 
#00 pc 0x88e1c libc.so (syscall + 28) (BuildId: 21cd09af0ad2ccf35d6b8ba2d064b3c4)
#01 pc 0x22a220 libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks + 136) (BuildId: 1ee2c234829500686eefa384068e67c8)
#02 pc 0x990208 libart.so (artJniMethodEnd + 344) (BuildId: 1ee2c234829500686eefa384068e67c8)
#03 pc 0x784e3c libart.so (art_jni_method_end + 12) (BuildId: 1ee2c234829500686eefa384068e67c8)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8115)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:703)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
        

It seems related to event dispatching. Can someone explain what nativePollOnce does, why it shows up in stack traces, and how I can identify the root cause of the issue?
I suspect it might be related to a NullPointerException in my fragment handling, but I’m unsure how to proceed. Any guidance would be appreciated!
How to fixed this ARN and how to reproduce.
